# How can I style a widget for a specific platform?

Tags: flutter

I would like to add a property/style a widget specifically for iOS or Android. I checked the Flutter docs but the example they have is more complex and focused on specific code.

Let's say I have a `Container` widget and I want to add some `padding` at the bottom but only for iOS devices. How can I achieve this?

```
Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10), //ONLY FOR iOS
      ),
```

Comment: you can use the native code by checking if  `Platform.isIOS` or you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **@GrahamD** for the idea I will use a **ternary operator** and the `Platform.isIOS` property to solve this:

```
import 'dart:io';

//This can also be used with Platform.isAndroid

Container(
  padding: Platform.isIOS ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10) : EdgeInsets.all(0),
)
```

That will check if the platform is **iOS** with `Platform.isIOS`. If it is **true** then it will add the `padding` I specified only for that platform. If it's **false** that means that `Platform.isAndroid` is **true** so it will not add any `padding`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate `Container` and use `if/else` to set up separate `Containers`.

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      ),
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10), //ONLY FOR iOS
      ),
}
```

Comment: To shorten bilaal's code you could define one container and use a ternary operator on the padding: property to add the edge inserts if it is ios, or null if it is not.

Comment: didnt know we could do that!

Comment: Yeah, Dart has some nice features. In the above situation it is useful as only one property changes. If there were several differences then your code is the way to go, of course.

Comment: I will do what @GrahamD proposed. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I also don't know why the question was down voted. The responsible person should add a comment.